# Message over MQTT received twice and three times if its payload exceeds 200MB

Tags: java, eclipse, mqtt, paho

I am running the samples shipped with the Paho Java client:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git/

Wether it is their own example, or a standalone hello world Paho demo from other sources, or even in conjunction with Spring Integration, the client somehow happens to receive a message more than one time, if its payload exceeds 200MB (this is not an exact figure, since I tested by gradually increasing the payload by 5MB message by message).

My broker is Mosquitto.
I tried all QOS configurations, Still the same.

Remarkably, this does not happen when working with the Paho Python library, using the same setup. So my environment (network, broker, publishing client, etc.) should be fine.

Comment: There isn't enough info to answer this. Can you provide: Paho version number, a striped down copy of the client code you are using? Do you have any logs you can show that refer to an issue with the message size or that show the same messages being received multiple times in error?

Have you tried using a different broker? [RSMB](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=d5bedadd-e46f-4c97-af89-22d65ffee070) or [MQ](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/develop_on_websphere_mq_advanced_at_no_charge?lang=en)

Comment: As @hardillb points out in an answer, this may be a Paho bug. MQTT isn't really designed for use with large messages. I see you have opened a bug on their bugzilla. It can take a while for someone to get round to fixing it but they normally get there in the end. Paho releases are scheduled to be coming more quickly this year so you might see it gets some attention.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a bug report than a question, you may do better raising this on the mailing list or bug tracker:

mailing list: https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/paho-dev

bug tracker: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&classification=Technology&list_id=4625660&order=Bug%20Number&product=Paho&query_format=advanced

Comment: I did already. Although I can never be 100%ly sure, that it is a bug. What if I am missing some parameters? That is why SO is made for.

Comment: Surely asking the developers of the library would be a better idea?